# Changing Type Array in Mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I mistakenly created a variable as an array and would like to remove the first element of the array and change the array type to simple strings. 
I have been playing around with changing types in mongo from integer to strings and using the $set to change strings to arrays, however I am unable to find a solution to this variation.

The following is the a piece of the document:

```
db.test.find({"ids":"XXX"}, {"accountability":1}).pretty()

{
"_id" : ObjectId("524c26006f73207e0d977522"),
    "accountability" : [
        {
            "environment" : null,
            "performance" : null,
        }
    ]
}
```

However when I tried to index it, the following appears:

```
db.test.find({"ids":"XXX"}, {"accountability.performance":1}).pretty()
{
"_id" : ObjectId("524c26006f73207e0d977522"),
"institution" : {
    "accountability" : [
        {
            "performance" : null
        }
    ]
}
}


db.test.find({"ids":"XXX"}, {"institution.accountability.0":1}).pretty()
{
"_id" : ObjectId("52435f0f6f73205f7d37a2b0"),
    "accountability" : {

    }
}
```

And lastly:

```
db.test.find({"ids":"XXX"}, {"accountability.0.performance":1}).pretty()
{
"_id" : ObjectId("524c26006f73207e0d977522"),
    "accountability" : [
        {

        }
    ]
}
```

I would appreciate any advice!
Thank you!

Comment: Just loop through all of the documents in the console, and make the fixes you need.